# Eclipse project export and CVS settings

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I exported about 100 projects in Eclipse from one machine to another. I did it this way to save some time rather than trying to pull all the data from CVS via VPN.  The problem is, when I did the project exports in Eclipse it did not preserve each projects CVS information.

Is there a way to update all these projects' CVS information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your CVS location, protocol and user going to stay the same and no files had changed, you can just zip up all cvs folders and unzip them over your projects at the new place.

Comment: That worked as far as importing the CVS settings.  The only way I got it to work was to import the settings from an archive file.  But it was still kind of wacky because CVS treated all the files as conflicting even though they were exactly the same. Not sure why Eclipse wouldn't allow for a mechanism to export the CVS settings when doing a project export.

Comment: Maybe because it is somewhat redundant, since you can usually checkout from CVS.